# Solving a system of equations using symmetry

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have $n$ positive real numbers $\lbrace P_i\rbrace_{i=1}^n$ and $\lbrace I_i\rbrace_{i=1}^n$ where $0<I_i\leq 1$.

If $S>0$, is there a unique solution to the equation $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=S$ so that for every $i\neq j$ we have $(P_i-x_i)*I_i=(P_j-x_j)*I_j$?

If so, is there a nice closed form for each $x_i$?

I believe there is such a solution. Also, whatever solution values of $\lbrace x_i \rbrace$ may be, solving for these is equivalent to finding the value of $(P_j-x_j)*I_j$.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

Well, wait a second. I hope this isn't in bad form, but after a lot of wasted time I think I figured it out.

If first we make a change of variables by letting $x_i'=P_i-x_i$, then we notice that $\sum x_i'=\sum P_i - \sum x_i = \sum P_i - S$. Now, recall that we are searching for $\lbrace x_i\rbrace$ so that for any $i,j$ we have $(P_i-x_i)I_i=(P_j-x_j)I_j$. Under change of variables, this becomes $I_ix_i'=I_jx_j'$. So we can re-imagine each $x_i'$, for single $k$, as $x_i'=\frac{k}{I_i}$. Using the sum above we can solve for $k$:

$$\sum x_i'=\sum \frac{k}{I_i}=\sum P_i-S$$
$$\Rightarrow k\sum  \frac{1}{I_i}=\sum P_i-S$$ 
$$\Rightarrow k =\frac{\sum P_i-S}{\sum\frac{1}{I_i}}$$

Then tracing our substitutions backwards tells us that $$x_i=P_i-\frac{\sum P_i-S}{\sum\frac{1}{I_i}}\frac{1}{I_i}$$

I argue now that this is the solution which I desired in OP. That $\sum x_i=S$:

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(P_i-\frac{(\sum_{k=1}^n P_k)-S}{(\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{I_j})}\frac{1}{I_i}\right)\\
&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^nP_i\right)-\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{(\sum_{k=1}^n P_k)-S}{(\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{I_j})}\frac{1}{I_i}\right)\\
&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^nP_i\right)-\frac{(\sum_{k=1}^n P_k)-S}{(\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{I_j})}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{I_i}\right)\\
&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^nP_i\right)-\left(\left(\sum_{k=1}^n P_k\right)-S\right)\\
&=S
\end{align}

Now for any $i,j$ we want to show that $(P_i-x_i)I_i=(P_j-x_j)I_j$. Our substitutions make this easy. 
$$k=k$$
$$\frac{I_i}{I_i}k=\frac{I_j}{I_j}k$$
$$I_ix_i'=I_jx_j'$$
$$I_i(P_i-x_i)=I_j(P_j-x_j)$$